# Maven pom and profile usage to generate two different war(part of main module) files with differing profile settings

Tags: maven, profile, pom.xml

I have a maven module project that has following modules:

Parent pom
 - core
 - web-commons
 - admin
 - web

Both web and admin have dependency on core and web-commons, and each module has its own profile.xml.

Until now, both our admin and web shared the same datasource name and web server, so all the way from core to web-commons we had a reference to this datasource name. (Actually a datasource macro placeholder that gets replaced from profiles.xml during build time).

However, we have to separate the datasources and now I am trying to figure out best way to do this.

Here is the code snippets for clarity.
Parent pom:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.my.groupId</groupId>
    <artifactId>parentArtifact</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    ...
    <modules>
        <<module>core</module>
        <module>web-commons</module>
        <module>admin</module>
        <module>web</module>
    </modules>
<project>
```

Core pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.my.groupId</groupId>
    <artifactId>core</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    ...
<project>
```

core Profiles.xml

```
<profilesXml xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/PROFILES/1.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/PROFILES/1.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/profiles-1.0.0.xsd">
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>DEV</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <properties>                
                 <datasource.name>web_datasource</datasource.name>
                 ...
            </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</profilesXml>
```

web-commons pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.my.groupId</groupId>
    <artifactId>web-commons</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    ...
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.my.groupId</groupId>
            <artifactId>core</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
<project>
```

web-commons Profiles.xml

```
<profilesXml xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/PROFILES/1.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/PROFILES/1.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/profiles-1.0.0.xsd">
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>DEV</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <properties>                
                 <datasource.name>web_datasource</datasource.name>
                 ...
            </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</profilesXml>
```

web pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <artifactId>parentArtifactId</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.my.groupId</groupId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.my.groupId</groupId>
    <artifactId>web</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.my.groupId</groupId>
            <artifactId>core</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.my.groupId</groupId>
            <artifactId>web-commons</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    ....
</project>
```

web profiles.xml

```
<profilesXml xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/PROFILES/1.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/PROFILES/1.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/profiles-1.0.0.xsd">
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>DEV</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <properties>                
                 <timeout>90</timeout>
                 ...
            </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</profilesXml>
```

admin pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <artifactId>parentArtifactId</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.my.groupId</groupId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.my.groupId</groupId>
    <artifactId>admin</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.my.groupId</groupId>
            <artifactId>core</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.my.groupId</groupId>
            <artifactId>web-commons</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    ....
</project>
```

admin profiles.xml

```
<profilesXml xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/PROFILES/1.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"   xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/PROFILES/1.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/profiles-1.0.0.xsd">
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>DEV</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <properties>                
                 <timeout>120</timeout>
                 ...
            </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</profilesXml>
```

Possible solutions:

- Change the core profiles.xml and all subsequent profiles.xml, and then run the 
  mvn clean package -PDEV_WEB and then again 
  mvn clean package -PDEV_ADMIN

core Profiles.xml

```
<profilesXml xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/PROFILES/1.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/PROFILES/1.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/profiles-1.0.0.xsd">
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>DEV_WEB</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <properties>                
                 <datasource.name>web_datasource</datasource.name>
                 ...
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>DEV_ADMIN</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <properties>                
                 <datasource.name>admin_datasource</datasource.name>
                 ...
            </properties>
        </profile>

    </profiles>
</profilesXml>
```

- Keep all the pom.xml and profiles.xml as-is and find a maven lifecycle point where we can generate web.war (that has core.jar and web-commons.jar that has web_datasource) and then generate admin.war (that has core.jar and web-commons.jar that has admin_datasource) Not sure how, but will have to investigate this further.

  - Separate web and admin deployment and keep the datasource name, but have two different web servers that have different datasource settings. [Least likely option]

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you make your artifacts environment-agnostic and make them read their configurations from e. g. system properties and/or config files that live outside the artifacts on the file system.

The kind of profile abundance you suggest seems to be a maintainance nightmare to me. What if you cut a release with the release plugin? Which profile would you activate then? Also, note that support for profile.xml was removed in Maven 3.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I do agree with you here. I wish I could have been involved from start but this one of the cases where you inherit bad eggs :)

Answer (score 0):

I ended up refactoring the code so that core and web commons do not have any direct reference to data source profile. All the data source entries have been removed from profiles.xml in core/web commons and new entries made in relevant modules (web/admin). [I know this is not a ideal solution]

Web now has its own entry for datasource-name in profiles.xml, similarly admin has its own datasource-name entry in profiles.xml. Also, core defined a jndi lookup data source spring bean, this is moved to relevant modules that have dependencies (web/admin).

Web profiles.xml

```
<profilesXmlmlns="http://maven.apache.org/PROFILES/1.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"   xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/PROFILES/1.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/profiles-1.0.0.xsd">
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>DEV</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <properties>                
                 <timeout>90</timeout>
                 <datasource-name>dev_web</datasource-name>
                 ...
            </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</profilesXml>
```

Admin profiles.xml

```
<profilesXmlmlns="http://maven.apache.org/PROFILES/1.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"   xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/PROFILES/1.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/profiles-1.0.0.xsd">
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>DEV</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <properties>                
                 <timeout>120</timeout>
                 <datasource-name>dev_admin</datasource-name>
                 ...
            </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</profilesXml>
```